# Read the xls file from Sharepoint using MS graph api for unknown range

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I need to access the xls file from sharepoint using Microsoft graph API and parse it.

This url gives correct data when the worksheet name and range is known.
/sites/site-Id/drives/drive-id/items/item-id/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='A1:C3')

But I am not sure how to get the data when the range is not known.

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to read all data cells without giving the range, you can however voice your interest in such a feature by going on to the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359629).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to read all data cells without giving the range as of now, you can however voice your interest in such a feature by going on to the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359629).